# Synonyms for big (grande), as in volume?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, solicitud-de-término

I'm trying to find a proper synonym for "*grande*", as in the quality of three dimensional objects of occupying space, to use with a regular object, such as a "big dog". I'll explain my specific situation below.

However, when searching, this is what I find:

> magnate, noble, prócer, ilustre, egregio, excelso, ínclito, sobresaliente, conspicuo

These have a totally different meaning, using the meaning of "great", as in good at something or respectable.

> monumental, considerable, mayúsculo, extraordinario, desmesurado, desmedido, ingente, inusitado, gigantesco, colosal, exorbitante, enorme, tremendo, grandioso

These, while referring to space, all involve the concept of being "too big" for something. While "*considerable*" does not have that effect, it also does not provide the idea of something being big (as another meaning for "*considerable*" is also to be acceptable).

> vasto, espacioso, extenso, holgado, amplio, ancho, alto, elevado

And finally, these ones are closer to that concept, but it is not completely correct to use them with the exact same meaning as "*grande*". A "*big bed*" is not the same as a "*vast bed*" nor a "*wide or tall bed*".

---

My specific purpose is to write this sentence. In the context, I have two dogs (one big, and one small), and I want to refer to the bigger one.

> Mi perro más grande tiene (...)

I want to avoid the use of "*grande*" because it could also be understood as older, when I actually want to talk about size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When talking about animals or objects, "*[grande](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=grande)*" is always about size, it only takes the meaning of age when it is said about a person, so your sentence is completely fine and impossible to be understood as "older". If you want to talk about your older dog, you would use "*[viejo](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?type=3&val=viejo)*":

> **viejo, ja.**
>   1. adj. Se dice de la persona de edad. Comúnmente puede entenderse que es vieja la que cumplió 70 años. U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. Se dice de los animales en igual caso, especialmente de los que son del servicio y uso domésticos.

So, you don't need any synonym as the precise word you are looking for is "*grande*", and there isn't any synonym for that.